# iPhone memory testing

Tags: iphone, testing, memory, memory-management

I'm testing iPhone allocations. I have a UITableView with 3 custom cells. When I switch between 2 views Malloc parameter is rising for about 0.1KB.

[image]

Is that normal? No leaks found.

Answer (score 1):

**The Simple Rule**: Only fire up Instruments if your app lags on an actual device.

**Extension to The Simple Rule**: Fire up Instruments to search leaks, but don't worry if they are from Apple libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The view needs to render again, this costs some memory, especially for the transitioning animation.

I don't think 100 bytes are something you need to be afraid of, but I'm pretty sure this is normal.